# REST API call on IOS to access Salesforce master-detail or child object

Tags: ios, rest, object, salesforce

I am making a REST API call on iOS to access objects on Salesforce. When I run the following code it works when the object on Salesforce is an independent object, but when the Salesforce object is a child object it does not work.

```
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT NAME, Id, Temperature__c FROM mySalessforceObject_Data__c LIMIT 10"];

[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

I get this error:

> sObject type 'mySalessforceObject_Data__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names., NSLocalizedFailureReason=INVALID_TYPE}

Comment: Simplified description, removed call for help, removed unnecessary tag